# Android Studio crashes on startup

Tags: android-studio

First time to Android Studio. I installed JDK and set up the environment variables. When running studio.exe or studio64.exe on the first time, the first screen flashes for a second and then I get the following error:

/*

```
Internal error. Please report to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues

com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:93)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:90)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationInfoImpl.getBuild(ApplicationInfoImpl.java:189)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startLogging(StartupUtil.java:300)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:106)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:33)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid version number: PK
```

*/

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment here by Studio's team member, It happens because of corrupted Installation

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60178

Comment by Android Studio's Team Member

> I think it's coincidence that it started working again -- nothing
>   you're doing in your code should cause this sort of crash in Studio.
>   It still feels like a corrupted install or something strange going on
>   in your environment. That magic number exception means a jar that's
>   part of Android Studio is getting scrambled.

I suggest you to try fresh Installation or, As it happens because of some internal Intellij's libraries problem.